# Get column value from insert with selectquery

Tags: oracle

I need to get the **personid** value from the query below. How can this be done without a trigger or functions?

```
INSERT INTO ps_persons (PERSONID,FAMILYNAME,FIRSTNAME,SECONDNAME,SEX) 
SELECT  SQ_PERSONS.NEXTVAL, cdo_forms.surname, cdo_forms.name, cdo_forms.patronymic, '-'  
FROM    cdo_forms  
WHERE   cdo_forms.formid = 81
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is the `returning` clause you're looking for. It works in PL/SQL, but can't work in `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... FROM` so - switch to a cursor `FOR` loop which then lets you use `INSERT INTO ... VALUES`.

Something like this:

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_id number;
  3  begin
  4    for cur_r in
  5      (SELECT  SQ_PERSONS.NEXTVAL id, cdo_forms.surname, cdo_forms.name,
  6               cdo_forms.patronymic, '-' sex
  7       FROM    cdo_forms
  8       WHERE   cdo_forms.formid = 81
  9      )
 10    loop
 11      INSERT INTO ps_persons (PERSONID,FAMILYNAME,FIRSTNAME,SECONDNAME,SEX)
 12      values (cur_r.id, cur_r.surname, cur_r.name, cur_r.patronymic, cur_r.sex)
 13      returning personid into l_id;
 14
 15      dbms_output.put_line('PersonID = ' || l_id);
 16    end loop;
 17  end;
 18  /
PersonID = 2

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * From ps_persons;

  PERSONID FAMILYNAME           FIRSTNAME            SECONDNAME S
---------- -------------------- -------------------- ---------- -
         2 Foot                 Little               B          -

SQL>
```